# On-chain privacy - centralised exchange that offers fresh deposit address?

Tags: exchanges, privacy

I'm a customer of Binance.

I have the same deposit address.

Someone asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794922/how-generate-new-deposit-tether-address-in-binance

> You can reach out to Customer Service if you’d like to change the deposit address manually.

In that case, I would like to use a different exchange and avoid leaving an obvious on-chain trail that multiple addresses belong to me.

Which exchange offers a button in the UI **"generate new address"**?

---

Alternatively, what are other options?

- `tornado.cash` is sanctioned
- https://changelly.com - cross-chain transfers

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge you can create sub accounts with its own wallet addresses in bigOne exchange. I don't know about other exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

## OKX

https://www.okx.com/balance/recharge/eth?sub=2

[image]

#### How I found out?

Their token is in TOP10 coin market cap so I was curious what they have to offer... Nice feature.

[image]